# IE8 not rendering borders

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I made a simple test page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id='test'>
        BORDER TEST!
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div#test{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

This doesn't work. And I've got this problem all over a site that I'm currently developing. Borders not rendering properly or simply just not showing up at all. This is happening on IE8, by the way.

A point in the right direction would be really nice.

PS: 
I've tried changing doctypes, but on my site other DTDs still don't fix the problem and, in fact, causes more.

Comment: Both your sample and Pro's work here on IE8, XPSP3.  But I've seen this problem of mutilated or disappearing borders before, never cared enough to find the root cause though.  I suspected the video driver / video hardware interaction on some computers - here it worked on an oldish nVidia 8600 GTS.

Comment: This isn't a HTML/CSS problem. IE8 on your computer is somehow broken.

Comment: hmm..well this problem has been found on two boxes a desktop and a laptop. both specs of which are immensely different. there's got to be something missing here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

change your doctype to above one. i have verified with IE 7 To IE 9. So definately This will help you. :)

Comment: I've tried that. I've tried most of what is found on this list. http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
    body,
html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div#test{
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    margin:10px auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='test'>
            BORDER TEST!
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my example. this should run.

Comment: this is essentially just changing the doctype and moving the css to the html file. I'm stumped.

Comment: you still not getting your requirement?

Comment: Nope nothing. I must be missing something here.

Comment: there must be some corrupted file in your IE. You must check your current code in full Utilized version of IE.